# Setting UserDefaults using the value of a table cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am new to Swift, and I am making an audio app. A user will see a `UITableView` and can click a file to play -- I want to record locally that this file has been played for when they come back to the app.

Based on the documentation, I am using `UserDefaults` as my method to capture this since it only matters for that user. Specifically, I am trying to pass the text of a `UITableView` cell that they select into a saved array for `UserDefaults`.

In my table, I pass this data here:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        // test to see if i can store row name in the defaults array
         let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
         let datastring = TableData[indexPath.row] as? String
         defaults.set(datastring, forKey: "SavedStringArray")

    }
}
```

The `TableData[indexPath.row]` is being converted into a string, and I believe that is a sequence that I can pass into an array.

In my next view, I try and call the `SavedStringArray` but it shows an empty set `[]`:

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()

    print(myarray)
```

My end game is that I want, if the user were to select the cells labeled "Show 1" and "Show 3" from the table would be to return a saved array in UserDefaults reading ["Show 1", "Show 3"].

Is there a better approach?

Comment: You are setting String in a default and retrieving it as array. No doubt, it would return empty array.

Comment: You are store string not string array(let datastring = TableData[indexPath.row] as? String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a small problem in your `prepareForSegue`

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        // test to see if i can store row name in the defaults array
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
        if let datastring = TableData[indexPath.row] as? String {
            if !myarray.contains(datastring) {
                myarray.append(datastring)
                defaults.set(myarray, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
                defaults.synchronize()
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am doing above is fetch the already saved Array in user default and append the new string to array and set it back to user defaults.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey Sandeep, just ran this and it works! I just need to figure out how to exclude repeating values if the user plays the track twice (not part of my question above). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not to your question, but by the way. Don't forget to call defaults.synchronize()

Comment: To prevent repeating values you could just check, if the value has been already included in the array by calling myarray.index(of:datastring)

Comment: @grigory-konovalov : I completely agree with your points I did not had my system with me I was posting answer from phone Ill update my answer with your suggestion in a while

Comment: @darkginger : Please take a look at the answer now this should solve your duplicate entry issue as well

Comment: Just ran it -- works great. You all rock. Confirming answer.

Comment: @darkginger : Am glad you have your problem solved buddy thanks to grigory-konovalov for valuable inputs

Comment: You do NOT need `defaults.synchronize()`. In fact, it's better to not use it. It doesn't "save" (saving is done automatically anyway), it syncs the whole default object, which can cause lag and issues. It's not only useless but is a problem sometimes. Just don't use it.

Comment: @Moritz, you're absolutely right. Normally one shouldn't use synchronize(). But it some cases it shall be called to prevent lose of data. For example, in applicationWillTerminate(_:) method of AppDelegate. That was my point.